# Keyboard is still visible after navigating away from search

Tags: bug, android-app

1. Go to any site like Stack Overflow.
2. Click on the search bar. The keyboard will be visible.
3. Go to Navigation bar and select Feed. The keyboard is still visible.

> [image: screen shot]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: XT1706
- OS Version: 6.0 (XT1706_S131_160905_ROW)